# How to combine two buttons into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have following two buttons:

```
<button type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1">Submit</button>

<button type="button" data-is_quote="1" data-button="simple_add_to_quote" data-product-type="simple" data-product-id="75448" id="add_to_quote">Submit</button>
```

the `#gform_submit_button_1` button validates form entries before submitting data to the server

and the `#add_to_quote` button submits form data without validating it

I want to be able to validate the form & submit it using the `#add_to_quote` button. Any solution?

Comment: Are you validatin with HTML 5?

Comment: both buttons are inside the form tag, right?

Comment: if there is no click handlers tied to `gform_submit_button_1`, why can't you just change the `type` to `submit` for `add_to_quote`?

Comment: But you say the #gform_submit_button_1 validates before it submits. So it already does submit right?

Comment: Yes, The first button does submit but I want it to be replaced with second button. The form should be validated & submitted using #add_to_quote button.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger click event of gform_submit_button_1 button on click of add_to_quote.

```
$("#add_to_quote").click(function() {
   $("#gform_submit_button_1").click();
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Isn't it possible to get rid of the first button and make use of it's ID somehow?

Comment: Try getting the selector of the form and do `$(<form-selector>).attr('novalidate', true).submit()`; (It should go inside the `$("#add_to_quote").click(function() {`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I get the problem right, but here is a possible solution :
Create a form element with an hidden input containing all the data-X values and a submit button that submits the form.

```
<form method="GET/POST" action="validation.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="data-validation" data-is_quote="1" data-button="simple_add_to_quote" data-product-type="simple" data-product-id="75448" id="add_to_quote">
   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="add_to_quote">
</form>
```

I hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

@Dhara Parmar solution is fine... but is missing the [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) and [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) like this:

```
$("#add_to_quote").click(function() {
   $(this).preventDefault(); //to stop submit
   $(this).stopPropagation();//to avoid the event bubbling up to other submit buttons, if any...
   $("#gform_submit_button_1").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the validation and submit functions of the form directly from the *type=button* click handler to make it behave like a *type=submit*

```
$("#add_to_quote").click(function () {
    if (!$("#TheForm").validate()) { //native validation triggered
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#TheForm").submit()
    }
});
```